# Why is expo-cli hanging after I run expo start?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using Expo to develop a React Native application. Metro Bundler should activate within a few seconds of me running the "expo start" command, but lately it has been intermittently failing to work. I get the response

`Starting project at <file path> ...`

but after that it just hangs. I've tried `npx expo start` and that doesn't work either.

I can get it working again by uninstalling and reinstalling Node, but the problem seems to arise again every few days. I was hoping somebody could help me understand the underlying problem here.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this now, how did you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try different Node version, I had the same problem with `v16.15.1`, when I changed to `v14.17.6` it started working immediately. You can use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm for switching node version easily.